# Django: calculate average, and sort by field in submodel

Tags: python, django, average

I have a Product model, with a one-to-many relation with a Rating model. I was previously storing an average_stars field in Product model, which I would update everytime a new Rating was added for that Product model. I would have a function in views.py which would return a QuerySet of all Product instances, ordered by average_star. Is there a way to do this more dynamically using a combination of .aggregate and .order_by, or anything along these lines.

In other words, is there a way to calculate the average for each product from all its respective Rating models, and sort them by that attribute? And which approach is better?

Comment: See aggregation there's an Avg class https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that your `Rating` model has a `stars` field, then you should use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
from django.db.models import Avg
Product.objects.annotate(average_stars = Avg('rating__stars')).order_by('-average_stars')
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I ended up doing, but I wanted to filter out products which did not have more than 5 ratings. I ended up running into this problem, when I tried to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617515/django-merging-querysets-after-annotation-does-not-work Any ideas?  ): thanks!